# How do I create a string using a loop variable in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, file-io

I have a loop like this:

```
for i=1:no

  %some calculations

  fid = fopen('c:\\out.txt','wt');
  %write something to the file
  fclose(fid);

end
```

I want data to be written to different files like this:

- for `i=1`, data is written to `out1.txt`
- for `i=2`, data is written to `out2.txt`
- for `i=3`, data is written to `out3.txt`
- etc.

Doing `'out'+ i` does not work. **How can this be done?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yet another option would be the function [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html):

```
fid = fopen(sprintf('c:\\out%d.txt',i),'wt');
```

Answer (score 3):

`filename = strcat('out', int2str(i), '.txt');`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
int2str(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

More simply:

```
for i=1:no
  %some calculations
  fid = fopen(['c:\out' int2str(i) '.txt'],'wt');
  %write something to the file
  fclose(fid);

end
```

PS. I don't believe Matlab strings need escaping except for '' (unless it's a format string for *printf style functions)

EDIT: See comment @MatlabDoug